# Java - Fastest Way to Reading Text Files Char by Char

Tags: java, file-io

I have nearly 500 text files with 10 million words. I have to index those words. What is the fastest way to read from a text file character by character? Here is my initial attempt:

```
InputStream ist = new FileInputStream(this.path+"/"+doc);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ist));

String line;

while((line = in.readLine()) != null){


   line = line.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    String word = "";

    for (int j = 0; j <= line.length(); j++) {
         char  c= line.charAt(j);
     // OPERATIONS

}
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine... What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: this isn't reading a character at a time, but why read character by character?

Comment: first: as tim noted, this is not reading char by char. please change the title. 
second: this sounds like a negligible amount of data. 
third: it sounds like this runs once. why do you care about performance at all? your app should have finished in the time you asked that question. (don't feel offended, i simply mean: stop worrying about performance until it's really a problem)

Answer (score 1):

`read()` will not give considerable difference in performance.

Read more: [Peter Lawery's comparison of read() and readLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594725/reading-inputstream-using-bufferedreader-readline-is-too-slow/5595030#5595030)

Now, coming back to your original question:
Input string: `hello how are you?`
So you need to index the *words* of the line, i.e.:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] splitString = line.split("\\s+");
   //Do stuff with the array here, i.e. construct the index.
}
```

Note: The pattern `\\s+` will put delimiter in the string as any whitespace like tab, space etc.

Comment: This is nice also because the split method will share with the originally read string, so it won't copy. This will actually gain some time over reading it character by character, and assembling it all on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read lines and then rescan the lines char by char. That way you are processing every character twice. Just read chars via BufferedReader.read().

Answer (score 0):

InputStreamReader's read() method can read a character at a time.

You can wrap it around FileReader or a BufferedReader or example.

Hope this helps!