# Reading a text file with char data

Tags: java

I have a text file with data like:

```
a1 a2 b1 b2 c1 a1b2c1 //Line 1
a2 b2 c2 d1 e1 b2c1   //Line 2
b1 c3 d2 e1 e2 c3     //Line 3
```

How do I read this file in Java and where and how to store the data? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? So far the only answer to your too general question is to read the file into a string... Tons of examples are available on the net.

Comment: We don't know what you're trying to do with it, which makes it hard to answer the "how to store" part. As for reading it... what have you tried, and what research have you done?

Comment: Have u tried looking at documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html

Comment: See this it may help you
 [HERE1][1]

[HERE2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151714/reading-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973109/java-fastest-way-to-reading-text-files-char-by-char

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna store it to a list:

```
public static void main(String... s) throws Exception {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("read.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = "";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           // process the line.
        list.add(line);
    }
    br.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**2 Questions remain:**

1. As said by Mr. Jon Skeet, **We don't know what you're trying to do with it, which makes it hard to answer the "how to store" part.**
2. **What do you want to read it as?** Do you want the entire data to be read as characters or do you want the numbers to be read as `int` ?

Since reading all characters is easy, I suggest you use `BufferedReader`. It will allow you to easily read sentences of paragraph.

To do this, you need to research:
1. `java.nio.Path` and `java.nio.Paths` (as of Java 7)
2. `java.nio.file.Files` to make `InputStream`
3. `InputStreamReader` as it will be needed by the `BufferedReader` constructor.
4. `BufferedReader` itself :)

**Here is a simple example**

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Vector;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;

public class TestReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path fileLocation = Paths.get("E:\\setup.txt"); // location of the file
        Vector<String> sentences = new Vector<String>();  //I do not know how many sentences are there
        InputStreamReader insReader = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String readSentence;

            insReader = new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(fileLocation,READ));
            reader = new BufferedReader(insReader);


            while((readSentence=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sentences.add(readSentence);
            }
        for(String a : sentences){
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily "read" a text file into memory. The problem is: what for? The key concept here is how to store it so the data is useful, i.e., it can be easily processed by your program. Since we ignore the purpose of the problem, I've assumed that you just need each particle as a string. For that purpose, a simple program like this will do:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReaderApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if ( args.length == 1 ) {
            String[] data = readData( args[ 0 ] );

            if ( data.length > 0 ) {
                for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    System.out.println( data[ i ] );
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println( "ERROR: problem reading file" );
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println( "ERROR: add the name of the text file" );
        }
    }

    public static String[] readData(String fileName)
    {
        ArrayList<String> toret = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName ) ) )
        {
            String line = f.readLine();
            while( line != null ) {
                String[] parts = line.split( " " );

                toret.addAll( Arrays.asList( parts ) );

                line = f.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exc)
        {
            toret.clear();
        }

        return toret.toArray( new String[ toret.size() ] );
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.