# BufferedReader in a loop

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm currently stuck in an Android problem. In a loop, I read from URLs which include an increasing id (`sensor`). If the maximal value is reached, the loop ends (`IOException` because of Error 500). My problem concerns the `BufferedReader`. If I specify the size (e.g. 8k), I cannot read more than these 8k, allthough the `BufferedReader` is recreated in every run of the loop (with a different uri) and every file I read from contains only one line (<8k).

If I leave out the size parameter, everything works fine but I get a warning like "default buffer size used. It would be better to be explicit...". What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
sensor = 0;
while (true) {
            try {
                // adapt uri
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(uri.resolve(String.valueOf(sensor))
                                .toURL().openStream()), 8*1024);

                // read from url
                s = in.readLine();
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            ... // do something with s

            sensor++;
}
```

Comment: It  is warning, you may ignore.

Comment: @Nambari: that does not explain the problem of not being able to read more than  8KB (accumulated)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "I cannot read more than these 8k"

Comment: I understand that he cannot read more than 8K accumulated over all the iterations. But I find that hard to believe. Each iteration of the loop is a new BufferedReader

Comment: move `in.close()` into the finally block:

    `BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(...);
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        if (in != null) in.close();
    }`

Comment: yes, I meant it accumulated. Thank you very much, ecbrodie, the finally block was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using your `s = in.readLine()` call inside a `while` loop, as in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594725/reading-inputstream-using-bufferedreader-readline-is-too-slow).  What you are doing with your code here is reading from the BufferedReader object only once, and you will get at most the size of the buffer (8k).  Subsequent reads will get you more data if there is any available.  If the result of the `readLine()` call is `null`, that means that there is no more data available to read.

Comment: No, that's not my problem. every file I read from consist of exactly one line, so one call is enough.